# how to make a scrollable canvas drawn on a surfaceview

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I'm drawing a map on a canvas into a surfaceview which is larger than the screen size and I need to be able to scroll through this map by dragging the screen. I'd like to either use canvas.translate(x,y) or Camera.translate(x,y,0) to move my canvas around. My problem is that I don't know how to set up my OnTouchListener so that it produces the appropriate x and y values to translate. I know a good way would be to listen for MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE and get the difference between x and y values received when dragging, but I don't know exactly how to implement this. Maybe a GestureDetector or some other listener would be better suited for the job?

Comment: yes `GestureDetector` is a way to follow, see `OnGestureListener#onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)` and `OnGestureListener#onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)`

Comment: thanks. I've successfully implemented a scrolling feature however I don't know what to use to offset my MotionEvent e.getX() and getY() in my onTouch method. If I don't offset these then my screen coordinates are no longer relative to my canvas and that messes up my collision detection. Any idea what a good offset would be?

Comment: Offset?  What offset?

Comment: when I translate my canvas, I need an offset value to properly scale the x value I receive in my onTouch meethod. But nvm I solved my issue already. Your gesturedetector comment put me on the right track though so feel free to make it an answer.

Comment: use View.scrollBy / scrollTo